# hana sql query or replacement of charIndex in sql hana

Tags: sql, hana

i have an requirement to build a SELECT sql hana query in which a column have only single record containg below values in comma separated.

```
Input :
rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext

Output :
    requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3


without using store procedure. 

Table : TestTable
column1                                 column2
pid1                                        rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext
pid2                                        rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext,rowtext
pid3                                        rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext
pid4                                        rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question so that you want to *remove* the `rowtext,` parts of the input string.  An additional difficulty is that there are dangling commas before and after the `rowtext` that should also be removed.

One way to do this is to use regular expressions similar to this:

```
with src as (select 'rowtext,requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext,rowtext' as INPUT
             from dummy)
select
    replace_regexpr ( ',?rowtext,?' in INPUT WITH '') as output
from src;

OUTPUT                                   
requiredText1,requiredText2,requiredText3
```

The `,?` in the search pattern matches zero or exactly one comma and the `rowtext` literally matches the search string.

Comment: Hi Lars thanks for your reply ,
we want to highlight 2 point 
1) what we know index of required text we want to 1,2,3. (if index start from 0) 
2) rowtext can be anything and for each row this can different.

basically we were not able to find alternative of chatAt in hana sql query

Comment: I still don’t understand what you want to achieve. You may want to update the question with more clarification. Something like `charAt` can be done with `substring`.